# How to replace a line with special characters of a file with Linux Bash instructions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to modify the line of a phpmyadmin configuration file, precisely, the file /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, in the line on the database server, where I need to change it with a bash instruction. I tried to do it with the sed and awk commands, but I still have no results.

The line that I want to modify is the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;
```

For the following value:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.0.10';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat ini
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;"

cat ini |  sed "s/\$dbserver/'192.168.0.10'/"
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.0.10';"
```

In other words, a

```
sed -i.bak-e "s/\$cfg\['Servers'\]\[\$i\]\['host'\] = \$dbserver;/\$cfg['Servers'][\$i]['host'] = '192.168.0.10';/" /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

should do the job. (with a .bak copy as a precaution).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only thing that I detail and I know that I did not mention, is that the configuration file, uses many times those variables in different ways, therefore, it would modify all of them in the file, causing problems.

The question is to escape the chain so that it can be replaced completely, since there is only one complete chain, just as I have shared it.

Comment: Excellent response, it works very well. Only the last PHP variable (\$i) needs to escape. It is a pity that you do not have enough reputation to evaluate your response positively. Thank you!

Comment: Right you are - edited.